# How to change User_Agent in PyQt4 QtWebkit

Tags: python, pyqt

Right now it looks like this:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/534.34 (KHTML, like Gecko) Qt/4.8.1 Safari/534.34
```

But I would like to change it to something like this:

```
Nokia5320XpressMusic/GoBrowser/1.6.0.70
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to subclass `QWebPage` and override the [`userAgentForUrl`](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qwebpage.html#userAgentForUrl) - method, then you can tell the `QWebView` to use your implementation using [`setPage`](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qwebview.html#setPage).